# Axios multiple request on get and post request error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, http-headers

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Navigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import gravatarUrl from "gravatar-url";
import "../assets/css/profile.css";

import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import API from "../backend";
import { isAutheticated } from "../auth";

let img;

const Profile = () => {
  // setting values
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    email: "",
    name: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    phone: "",
    country: "",
    role: "",
    reg: "",
    error: "",
    success: "",
  });

  // state to know if someone clicked on the edit button
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

  // handaling onchange event
  const onHandleChange = (val) => (event) => {
    setUpdate({ ...update, [val]: event.target.value });
  };

  // Updating the new value from input
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState({
    name: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    phone: "",
    country: "",
    error: "",
  });

  // state to check if someone click on submit
  const [didSubmit, setDidSubmit] = useState(false);

  // destructuring values from data (useState)
  const { email, name, city, state, phone, country, reg, role } = data;

  // destructuring token from localstorage
  const { token } = isAutheticated();

  // dataObject for api call
  const dataType = {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  // get api call
  const axiosGetCall = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await Axios.get(`${API}/user/profile`, dataType);

      // seting image
      img = gravatarUrl(res.data.user.email, { size: 200 });
      // set data
      setData({
        ...data,
        email: res.data.user.email,
        name: res.data.user.name,
        city: res.data.user.city,
        state: res.data.user.state,
        phone: res.data.user.phone,
        country: res.data.user.country,
        role: res.data.user.role,
        reg: res.data.user.createdAt,
        success: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error log: `, error);
      setData({
        ...data,
        error: error.response.data.error,
        success: false,
      });
    }
  };

  // post call/update
  const axiosUpdateCall = async () => {
    // token
    const { token1 } = isAutheticated();
    // new dataObject for post call
    const dataToken = {
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${token1}`,
      },
    };
    try {
      const res = await Axios.post(`${API}/user/profileEdit`, dataToken);

      console.log(`res:`, res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error log: `, error);
      setData({
        ...data,
        error: error.response.data.error,
        success: false,
      });
    }
  };

  // For get api call
  useEffect(() => {
    axiosGetCall();
  }, []);

  // for post api call if some clicked on submit
  useEffect(() => {
    if (didSubmit) {
      axiosUpdateCall();
    }
  }, [didSubmit]);

  // prevent default
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setDidSubmit(true);
  };

  // Normal profile HTML CODE
  const profileMain = () => {
    return (
      <div className="container bootdey flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
        <div className="media align-items-center py-3 mb-3">
          <img src={img} alt="" className="d-block ui-w-100 rounded-circle" />
          <div className="media-body ml-4">
            <h4 className="font-weight-bold mb-0">
              {name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)}
            </h4>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setEdit(true);
              }}
              className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
            >
              Edit
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <Link to="" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
              Go back
            </Link>
            &nbsp;
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="card mb-4">
          <div className="card-body">
            <table className="table user-view-table m-0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Registered:</td>
                  <td>{reg.slice(0, 10)}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Verified:</td>
                  <td>
                    <span className="fa fa-check text-primary"></span>&nbsp; No
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Role:</td>
                  <td>{role.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + role.slice(1)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Status:</td>
                  <td>
                    <span className="badge badge-outline-success">Active</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <hr className="border-light m-0" />
        </div>

        <div className="card">
          <hr className="border-light m-0" />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h6 className="mt-4 mb-3">Personal Details:</h6>
            <table className="table user-view-table m-0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Full Name:</td>
                  <td>{name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)} </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Email:</td>
                  <td>{email}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Phone:</td>
                  <td>{phone}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>City:</td>
                  <td>{city}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>State:</td>
                  <td>{state}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Country:</td>
                  <td>{country}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  // Profile when someone clicked on edit
  const profileEdit = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container bootdey flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
          <div className="media align-items-center py-3 mb-3">
            <img src={img} alt="" className="d-block ui-w-100 rounded-circle" />
            <div className="media-body ml-4">
              <h4 className="font-weight-bold mb-0">
                {name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)}
              </h4>
              &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="card mb-4">
            <div className="card-body">
              <table className="table user-view-table m-0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Registered:</td>
                    <td>{reg.slice(0, 10)}</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>Verified:</td>
                    <td>
                      <span className="fa fa-check text-primary"></span>&nbsp;
                      No
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Role:</td>
                    <td>{role.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + role.slice(1)}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Status:</td>
                    <td>
                      <span className="badge badge-outline-success">
                        Active
                      </span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <hr className="border-light m-0" />
          </div>

          <div className="card">
            <hr className="border-light m-0" />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h6 className="mt-4 mb-3">Personal Details:</h6>
              <table className="table user-view-table m-0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Full Name:</td>
                    <td>
                      <div className="col-3">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          className="form-control"
                          onChange={onHandleChange("name")}
                          defaultValue={name}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>{email}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td>
                      <div className="col-3">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          className="form-control"
                          onChange={onHandleChange("phone")}
                          defaultValue={phone}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>City:</td>
                    <td>
                      <div className="col-3">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          className="form-control"
                          onChange={onHandleChange("city")}
                          defaultValue={city}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>State:</td>
                    <td>
                      <div className="col-3">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          className="form-control"
                          onChange={onHandleChange("state")}
                          defaultValue={state}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Country:</td>
                    <td>
                      <div className="col-3">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          className="form-control"
                          onChange={onHandleChange("country")}
                          defaultValue={country}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                Submit
              </button>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setEdit(false);
                }}
                className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

  // toast to show error
  const errorToast = () => {
    toast(`${update.error}`, {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: false,
      hideProgressBar: true,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
      theme: "dark",
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer
        position="top-right"
        autoClose={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        theme="colored"
      />

      {/* {error && (
        <>
          <Navigate to="/signout" />
        </>
      )} */}
      {edit === true ? (
        <>
          {profileEdit()} <br />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          {profileMain()} <br />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

i'm calling two api calls..

1. get request and everything is working fine.
2. post request, here i'm unable to send the token to the backend..

i used same method for get request and it was working fine, but when used same method on post request i'm unable to send token..

is there something that i'm missing ?

i have added comment in each line of code.. my english is poor.
sorry and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for `Axios.post()` is for the POST data and you're setting headers there. Pass an empty object (if you want to have empty POST data) and move your headers (`dataToken`) to the third argument:

```
const res = await Axios.post(`${API}/user/profileEdit`, {}, dataToken);
//                                                      ^set POST data here
```

From the [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro):

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

Comment: @GeorgePrethesh glad to help. If this solved it, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. This helps others identify the solution.